# After deploy identityserver3 makes error for The client application is not known or is not authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity, identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm new in IdentityServer3.

When I implement IdentityServer3 on my localhost - everything works well, but after I deploy it on IIS and go to the authorize page it shows an error.
The text of the error is :The client application is not known or is not authorized.
But clientId is configured propperly.

Here is my client code:

```
    new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientName = "sth",
                ClientId = "mfc",
                Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowRememberConsent = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sth"]
                },
                 PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sth"]
                },
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 360,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>() { "openid", "profile" , "roles", "WebAPI" }
            }
```

And the startup class of my client project is:

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
            ClientId = "mfc",

            //In the Scope we ask what to include
            Scope = "openid profile roles WebAPI",
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var sub = id.FindFirst(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject);
                    var roles = id.FindAll(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(id.AuthenticationType,
                            IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    nid.AddClaim(sub);
                    nid.AddClaims(roles);


                    // keep the id_token for logout
                    nid.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    nid.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(nid, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks.!

Comment: As a side note: If you are new in IdentityServer3 then I strongly advice that you start with IdentityServer4. As IdentityServer3 isn't going to be maintained anymore: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/06/end-of-identityserver3-maintenance/

Comment: Is the website on IIS running with ssl? Because Ids will not allow login from an unsecured website. At least, this is how it works in Ids4. I've never worked with Ids3.

Comment: Configure logging for IdentityServer and see what it says. Your configuration seems legit, but the logs will tell more. Only one thing I'm noting - your custom scope (WebAPI), is it registered in IdentityServer's scopes?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yes it is running on IIS with ssl.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 I don't have full access to our server, So i can't see the logs at least today.And about my webAPI scope,Yes it registered in my IdentityServer scopes.

Comment: @Mohsen - Sorry but it can be a lot of things. The logs are going to tell what is it. It can even be a typo mistake in the urls. I'm not saying that this is the problem, I just say - look at the logs. That's what they are for

Comment: Yes, look at the logs. I often encounter this error when there is a typo in redirect URL. e.g trailing '/' in the redirect URI.